# Exploiting a buffer overflow in ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, ubuntu, encoding

I'm trying to exploit some buffer overflow through linux terminal of a program I've written for self education. I'm inputting a string usnig `scanf("%s")` and my goal is to overrwrite the return address over the stack frame
my problem is the following, I need to overwrite the return address to become the value of `0x08048934` hence when taking a consideration of the endianity within my computer I need to enter the sequence of byte hex value of

```
0x34 0x89 0x04 0x08
```

and this is where I'm finding difficulty.... It appears to me that I can't enter directly into the ubuntu terminal the values of **extended-ascii** characters, such as the one with the value of 0x89 or 137 in decimal which is an extended value...

How do I overcome this difficulty and create a string that contains the following values and allows me to create the desired address

p.s. When using `ctrl` + `shift` + `u` and the hex value 0x89 the character gets coded as a c1 utf-8 character hence the literal I get it `\xc2\x89`
**also this may be unclear, I may be dependent on some output prints of the program such as address or etc hence I must type in the manipulated value during runtime of the program (After it has started executing) and not before**

Comment: Well, this doesn't really have anything to do with security. The question is just about inputting non-ascii (or non-your-current-locale) character. Buffer overflow is irrelevant to it.

Comment: I agree with @domen. Just for your idea, you need to parse Hex to a string and then input that string into the program. You can do a simple output redirection from hex to string converter to your program

Comment: technically yes it isn't yet it is more likely that people whom are familiar with computer security would know techniques that allows to overcome such difficulties

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -en '\x34\x89\x04\x08' | your_program
```

Comment: what if I'm dependent on some output of the program? and cant do it ahead of it running (which is my actual problem )

Comment: echo -en "\x${a0}\x${a1}..."?

Comment: But surely it's not way much work than typing, which you were trying to do originally :P

Comment: ehhh sorry I didn't quiet get the last one... just to make things more clear, e.g I'm somehow getting the output of the stack base address and I need to overwrite another thing regardless the return address hence I can't do it ahead of execution...

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Maybe you can make a script interact with your software (or a script that waits for your input, and then transforms it into binary?). Or maybe you could use one of /proc/<pid>/fd/, to feed data directly there.

Comment: I've thought about using python and Popen but I've failed doing so, could you please expand? /proc/pid allows me to divert stdin/out? @domen

Comment: Wrap it in expect or a two way pipe to read Syd out before writing the address on stdin?